# uploading external csv file to highcharts not working

Tags: jquery, csv, highcharts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Highcharts Data loading using CSV</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
         $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: "line"
            },
            title: {
                text: "Fruit Consumtion"
            },
            xAxis: {
                title:{
                    text:"time(in sec)"
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: "pitch value"
                }
            },
            data: {
                csv: data
                //csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }
            });
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code worked for csv data embedded in a hidden div. However when I try exporting external csv data, its throwing error.

[image]

Comment: The value in `data` will just be a string holding the contents of the CSV file. You need to turn that string in to an array.

Comment: Do you run a chart on a webserver? Ajax cannot be triggered from local file system.

Comment: Do you have a server setup? Like apache or nodejs? You need a server because you cannot make XMLHttpRequests at a `file://` URL

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks.I tried doing the same.Later, I used php command file_get_contents() and got the desired result.

Comment: Thanks @rafaelcastrocouto. Using php function file_get_contents() helped with .txt file for the CSV values

Comment: Thanks @SebastianBochan

Answer (score 0):

You need a server setup, like [apache](http://www.apache.org/) or [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/).

You need a server because you cannot make [XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) at a file:// URL