# HighCharts: loading from csv file, blank page in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, highcharts

I have the following HTML/JS below (taken from a Highcharts sample) that is intended to load some basic data from a CSV file. But when loading the .htm, it's just blank.

I've tried various things like using F12 in IE to view the Console; there are no errors. If I View Source, I can correctly see the HTML as it should be. But the page is just blank. If I use IE's Debugger and place a breakpoint on the `.get()` line, Step Into seems to jump to the bottom of the closing `get` bracket?

The CSV file is in the same folder as the .htm, and the data looks like:

```
 DateTime,Count
    10/11/2016 00:00:00,20
    10/12/2016 00:00:00,12
    10/13/2016 00:00:00,5
```

I verified there's no blank line at the end of the file.

The HTML/JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the CSV and create the chart
    $.get('count_changes.csv', function (data) {

        $('#container').highcharts({

            data: {
                csv: csv
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Daily visits at www.highcharts.com'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: Google Analytics'
            },

            xAxis: {
                tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
                tickWidth: 0,
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                labels: {
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 3,
                    y: -3
                }
            },

            yAxis: [{ // left y axis
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 3,
                    y: 16,
                    format: '{value:.,0f}'
                },
                showFirstLabel: false
            }, { // right y axis
                linkedTo: 0,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                opposite: true,
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3,
                    y: 16,
                    format: '{value:.,0f}'
                },
                showFirstLabel: false
            }],

            legend: {
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 20,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 0
            },

            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                crosshairs: true
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function (e) {
                                hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                    pageOrigin: {
                                        x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                                        y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                                    },
                                    headingText: this.series.name,
                                    maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' +
                                        this.y + ' visits',
                                    width: 200
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'All visits',
                lineWidth: 4,
                marker: {
                    radius: 4
                }
            }, {
                name: 'New visitors'
            }]
        });
    });

});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/static/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/static/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/static/highslide.css" />

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see where you are giving your series the data.

Comment: @bassxzero This is taken from a working example. So what am I missing? I did not see anything like that in the example either.

Comment: change $.get('count_changes.csv', function (data) to  $.get('count_changes.csv', function (csv)

Comment: @bassxzero I tried that as well earlier. Same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered this:

You need a server because you cannot make XMLHttpRequests at a file:// URL

[uploading external csv file to highcharts not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889440/uploading-external-csv-file-to-highcharts-not-working)